# How to find UDP packet Delay time

Tags: networking, udp, wireshark, network-monitoring, wireshark-dissector

How to find UDP packet's round trip time from Wireshark tool??i am getting lot of upd packets at a time.So i want to find for each packet,how long it take to send a resposne.Is any other tool for accomplishing this??

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark can not help in this, since it only records time it sees UDP packet sent.

Try `ping remote_host_IP_addr` - it gives statistics regarding RTT (round trip time)

Comment: But for a udp packet,there will be an acknowledgement.So i want to find difference between them.

Comment: There's ACK for TCP packets, but not for UDP.

Comment: i am getting lot of upd packets at a  time.So i want to find for each packet,how long it take to send a resposne.Is any other tool for accomplishing this??

Comment: ping. You can use also traceroute (Linux)/tracert(Win) to see route (machines) your packets are delivered by and find where is delay comes from.